# Parsing csv file with english and hindi characters in python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, utf-16

I am trying to parse a csv file which has both english and hindi characters and I am using utf-16. It works fine but as soon as it hits the hindi charatcer it fails. I am at a loss here.

Heres the code -->

```
import csv
import codecs

csvReader = csv.reader(codecs.open('/home/kuberkaul/Downloads/csv.csv', 'rb', 'utf-16'))
for row in csvReader:
        print row
```

The error that I get is Traceback (most recent call last):

```
>  File "csvreader.py", line 8, in <module>
>     for row in csvReader: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 11-18: ordinal not in range(128)
> kuberkaul@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

How do I solve this ?

Edit 1:

I tried the solutions and used unicdoe csv reader and now it gives the error :

> > UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
> >     0: ordinal not in range(128)

The code is :

```
import csv
import codecs, io


def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')

filename = '/home/kuberkaul/Downloads/csv.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(codecs.open(filename))
  print reader
for rows in reader:
  print rows
```

Comment: Your indentation was broken as pasted. I fixed it here, but it looks like the kind of problem you get when mixing tabs and spaces, so you should look at your actual code carefully. (And use an editor that helps you with this in the future—ideally by converting tabs into spaces automatically.)

Comment: If you don't need to access the data at a character level, you can simply open file in binary mode, without trying to decode anything at all.

Comment: @doukremt: No you can't. `csv` can't handle UTF-16, or anything else that can have NUL bytes in the encoding. That's explained in the very same note that I already linked to.

Comment: As a side note, is there a reason you're using `codecs.open` instead of `io.open`? Unless you need to be compatible with old versions of Python, `io` is almost always better for uses like this. It's faster, less buggy, more forward-compatible to 3.x, and, in the edge cases where they do different things, `io` is usually the one that does what you want.

Comment: Another side note: Is there a reason you have to use Python 2.7? Using 3.x would solve this problem (and also solve the problem with `print`ing that you're likely to run into next, assuming you're on Windows).

Comment: @abarnert: you're right, my bad.

Comment: First, this looks like a new problem, which means you should post a new question. Second, posting an error without the traceback, or at least which line of code it came from, isn't very helpful. However, I think I can guess your problem: You're calling `codecs.open(filename)` with no other parameters, so presumably the error is inside the `codecs` module, trying to interpret UTF-16 as ASCII, and failing on the very first byte (which is the first half of a UTF-16-LE BOM, `0xff`). This problem wasn't in your original code, my answer, or the linked example, so I don't know why you changed it.

Comment: As a side note, it makes your code much easier to read if you consistently use `encode`/`decode` or 2-parameter `unicode`/`str`, instead of mixing the two up. If you `yield line.encode('utf-8')` into the reader, `yield [cell.decode('utf-8') for cell in row]` out of the reader, and it'll be much easier to tell that you're matching things up properly.

Comment: Finally: Is there a reason you're explicitly encoding to UTF-8 to print? It sounds like you're on Windows, so it's unlikely that your command prompt is in UTF-8; it's probably in cp1252 or cp1137 or something like that. If so, you're just going to get another error or mojibake output once you fix this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) says, in a big Note near the top:

> This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe; see the examples in section Examples.

If you follow link to the example, it shows you the solution: Encode each line to UTF-8 before passing it to `csv`. They even give you a nice wrapper, so you can just replace the `csv.reader` with `unicode_csv_reader` and the rest of your code is unchanged:

```
csvReader = unicode_csv_reader(codecs.open('/home/kuberkaul/Downloads/csv.csv', 'rb', 'utf-16'))
for row in csvReader:
    print row
```

---

Of course the `print` isn't going to be very useful, as the `str` of a list uses the `repr` of each element, so you're going to get something like `[u'foo', u'bar', u'\u0910\u0911']`…

You can fix that in the usual ways—e.g., `print u', '.join(row)` will work if you remember the `u`, and if Python is able to guess your terminal's encoding (which it can on Mac and modern linux, but may not be able to on Windows and old linux, in which case you'll need to map an explicit `encode` over each column).